# Vue.js + Prevent watch trigger on load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I want to disable a button by default and enable it only when input value is changed.

So i am using a boolean flag which is true by default and is set to false only when input changes
The input v-model is tied to an Object property.

The problem is when the page loads for the first time, it triggers the watch property and boolean value is set to false. hence the button is never disabled.How i can make the watch to trigger only when the value is changed?

Below is the code -

```
class GridFilters
{

constructor(grid)
{
    this.grid = grid;
    this.filterName = '';
    this.buttonflag=true;
    this.filterError=false;
}
}

export default {
  data() {
    return {
    gridFilter : {};
  };
 },
 created () {
  this.gridFilter = new GridFilters(this); 
},
watch
{
 'gridFilter.filterName': function ()
        {
            this.gridFilter.buttonflag= false;
        },
}
};
```

html

```
<input placeholder="Enter a name" v-model="gridFilter.filterName" ref="filterName" @keydown="gridFilter.filterError=false" />
<button @click="save()" v-bind:disabled="gridFilter.buttonflag?true:false">Save Filter</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to ignore the change if the previous value is `undefined`. The watch handler receives the new value and old value as its first and second argument, respectively:

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    'gridFilter.filterName': function (newVal, oldVal) {
      if (oldVal === undefined) {
        return
      }

      this.gridFilter.buttonflag = false
    },
  },
}
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-ignore-first-watch-trigger?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Alternatively, you could improve the UX by setting `gridFilter.buttonflag` to `true` when the new value of `gridFilter.filterName` is empty. That way, if the user decides to clear the input, the button gets disabled again:

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    'gridFilter.filterName': function (newVal) {
      this.gridFilter.buttonflag = !newVal
    },
  },
}
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-disable-button-on-empty-input?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need that watcher at all, I think. You can use the value of `gridFilter.filterName` directly on the button, like:

```
<button … :disabled=“gridFilter.filterName === ‘’”>
```

So if `filterName` is an empty string, as you set it initially, the button will be disabled.